# didSelectRowAtIndexPath, pushViewController and a little lable

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, uitableview

I have a table controller in which I use *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* to navigate from the pushed cell to another view. In it I initialize new view controller and push some data in it. After that I do *pushViewController*.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    ServicesModel *service = [services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ServiceViewController *serviceViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceView"];

    serviceViewController.serviceModel = service;
    NSLog(@"Set model %@", service.title);

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.serviceController pushViewController:serviceViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In my *ServiceViewController* I have a label *serviceTitle* and *ServiceModel* property for selected service

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *serviceTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ServiceModel *serviceModel;
```

Using *viewDidLoad* I'm trying to change text of the label

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad %@", self.serviceModel.title);
    self.serviceTitle.text = self.serviceModel.title;
}
```

Also I'm trying to access model in *viewDidAppear*

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear %@", self.serviceModel.title);
}
```

but when view opens, label is empty. Why? What am I doing wrong? The most strange is the log:

```
(-[ServiceViewController viewDidLoad]) (ServiceViewController.m:43) viewDidLoad (null)
(-[ServicesTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]) (ServicesTableViewController.m:127) Set model Google.com
(-[ServiceViewController viewDidAppear:]) (ServiceViewController.m:36) viewDidAppear (null)
```

It shows that *viewDidLoad* fires before I assign the model property. And in *viewDidAppear* model property is still null. How it can be?

Comment: You need to set some breakpoints and see what is happening, but my guess is that you already have a segue defined in the storyboard which is pushing your view controller, and the code in your didSelectRow method is either doing nothing (no VC is being created, or you're not presenting it - what is self.serviceController, for example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. The first one, as 0x7fffffff mentioned, is that you're instantiating your controller incorrectly (it should be initWithNibName:bundle: if made in a xib, and like 0x7fffffff said if in a storyboard).

Second, you can't access the label in serviceViewController from didSelectRowAtIndexPath, because its view has not been loaded yet. So, instead of setting the label in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you should have a string property in serviceViewController, and give it the value service.text. Then in viewDidLoad, you can populate your label with that string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your advice but still no result. I updated my code and question. Can you please look at it?

Comment: @lanin, I don't see anything wrong with your code. You're assigning service to serviceViewController.service right after you instantiate it -- that should happen before viewDidLoad,, which doesn't occur until you do the push. Just for a test, try changing the label in viewDidAppear instead, and see if that works.

Comment: I can't understand what is happening. _viewDidAppear_ fires after I assign the property. But when I try to access to it in this function to set the label text, it appears as null!

Comment: @lanin, I think your problem is that you're instantiating serviceViewController with alloc init. This is probably a different instance from the one you push on screen. Where is that controller's view made? Storyboard? Xib?

Comment: Storyboard. It has ServiceView id. That's why I init it like `ServiceViewController *serviceViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceView"];`.

Comment: @lanin Sorry, going back and forth between too many posts, I forgot that you had changed that. So, if you log serviceModel in viewDidAppear it logs null? It would be helpful to edit your post to take out all the old code, and just show what you're doing now. Include the logs and what result they give.

Comment: @lanin, The only thing I can think of is that something is wrong in your controller structure -- there's nothing wrong with the code you posted, and the log in didSelectRow should definitely print before the one in viewDidLoad of ServicesViewController. If you can post the whole project somewhere or email it to me (rdelmar@comcast.net), I'll take a look. It's hard to diagnose these kinds of problems without being able to actually test the app.

Answer (score 1):

Is the label missing altogether, or do you see it and it just didn't receive updated text? If the label is missing, then it's probably a problem in how you're creating the view controller. If for example, you're using storyboards, you should be accessing the view controller like this:

```
ServiceViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeStoryBoardID"];
```

Instead of this:

```
ServiceViewController *serviceViewController = [[ServiceViewController alloc] init];
```

If however, you can see the label, but it just hasn't updated it's text, the first thing you should to is examine the connections inspector in Interface Builder, and verify that the IBOutlet for the label is properly linked.

Comment: Thank you to your advice. I'm using storyboards and changed my code using you first example. But still I see empty space instead of my label. I did some changes in my code and added them to my question. Can you please look at them?

Comment: No, viewWillAppear fires before I set the property too (